# Extensible registry of types

Tags: rust, convention

I have a program that can read multiple audio formats. A shared module could provide a trait, `AudioFileReader`, that has common methods for reading audio data as well as a registry for associating readers to file extensions.

Rather than have all the possible audio format readers built into the module, it would be useful for this module to be extensible, so that clients of the module can provide `AudioFileReader`s for new formats (either when linked into an executable or via a plug-in system).

What would be a conventional Rust way to build a system like this? Is there a way to avoid needing a global static registry while without losing extensibility?

Comment: It sounds like you know the answer (use traits), so maybe I misunderstood the question. Could you explain why traits are not on there own sufficient?

Comment: Do you want the modules to be registered on compile-time or run-time? If compile-time, I think macros are the most common solution. For run-time, I'm not sure.

Comment: At run-time, that allows for the use of plug-in systems and other extensions to the design.

Comment: @PeterHall, I think the more interesting part is how to build the registry, and also whether it would be possible automatically register the AudioFileReaders as opposed to having to list them all in `main()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build such a registry by using a `lazy_static` global, which contains a map of extension name to `Box<AudioFileReader>`.

You would have to list them all in main (or have main call init functions). There's no way to automatically do this, Rust has no life before main.

Comment: There are crates now that break the paradigm, ctor (https://crates.io/crates/ctor) which is used to implement inventory (https://crates.io/crates/inventory).