# How do I make a struct for FFI that contains a nullable function pointer?

Tags: c, rust

I have an existing C program that loads shared library plugins.  The main C program interacts with those plugins through a C struct containing integers, strings, function pointers, etc.  How can I create such a plugin from Rust?

Note that the (real) C program cannot be changed, nor can the API be changed, those are fixed, existing things, so this is not a question about "how best to support plugins in Rust", it's how can Rust make `*.so` files which interoperate with an existing C program.

Here's a simplified example of a C program + C plugin:

```
/* gcc -g -Wall test.c -o test -ldl
   ./test ./test-api.so
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

struct api {
  uint64_t i64;
  int i;
  const char *name;                /* can be NULL */
  void (*load) (void);             /* must not be NULL */
  void (*hello) (const char *str); /* can be NULL */
};

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  void *dl = dlopen (argv[1], RTLD_NOW);
  if (!dl) { fprintf (stderr, "%s: %s\n", argv[1], dlerror ()); exit (1); }
  struct api *(*get_api) (void) = dlsym (dl, "get_api");
  printf ("calling get_api ...\n");
  struct api *api = get_api ();
  printf ("api->i64 = %" PRIi64 "\n", api->i64);
  printf ("api->i = %d\n", api->i);
  if (api->name)
    printf ("api->name = %s\n", api->name);
  printf ("calling api->load ...\n");
  api->load ();
  if (api->hello) {
    printf ("calling api->hello ...\n");
    api->hello ("world");
  }
  printf ("exiting\n");
  exit (0);
}
```

```
/* gcc -g -shared -fPIC -Wall test-api.c -o test-api.so */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

static void
load (void)
{
  printf ("this is the load function in the plugin\n");
}

static void
hello (const char *str)
{
  printf ("hello %s\n", str);
}

static struct api {
  uint64_t i64;
  int i;
  const char *name;
  void (*load) (void);
  void (*hello) (const char *str);
} api = {
  1042,
  42,
  "this is the plugin",
  load,
  hello,
};

struct api *
get_api (void)
{
  return &api;
}
```

Here's what I wrote in Rust to try to get a plugin, but it doesn't compile:

```
extern crate libc;

use libc::*;
use std::ffi::*;
use std::ptr;
use std::os::raw::c_int;

#[repr(C)]
pub struct api {
    i64: uint64_t,
    i: c_int,

    name: *const c_char,

    load: extern fn (),
    hello: extern fn (), // XXX
}

extern fn hello_load () {
    println! ("hello this is the load method");
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn get_api () -> *const api {
    println! ("hello from the plugin");

    let api = Box::new (api {
        i64: 4201,
        i: 24,
        name: CString::new("hello").unwrap().into_raw(), // XXX memory leak?
        load: hello_load,
        hello: std::ptr::null_mut,
    });

    return Box::into_raw(api); // XXX memory leak?
}
```

This is compiled using `Cargo.toml` containing:

```
[package]
name = "embed"
version = "0.1.0"

[dependencies]
libc = "0.2"

[lib]
name = "embed"
crate-type = ["cdylib"]
```

The error is:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:32:16
   |
32 |         hello: std::ptr::null_mut,
   |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected "C" fn, found "Rust" fn
   |
   = note: expected type `extern "C" fn()`
              found type `fn() -> *mut _ {std::ptr::null_mut::<_>}`

error: aborting due to previous error
```

I didn't get to try loading the module but when I tried this before with the real program the fields were all wrong indicating something much more fundamental was wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Idiomatic Rust plugin system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44708483/idiomatic-rust-plugin-system)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Rust have a dlopen equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22461457/does-rust-have-a-dlopen-equivalent)

Comment: You say that your Rust example doesn't compile. How do you try to compile it and what errors do you get?

Comment: `dlopen` is the wrong half of the equation: that's how you load a shared library. OP's C program presumably already does that, which is why they want to *create* a shared library (although I'm not clear on what the actual problem is).

Comment: [This (very old) issue may help with your compilation problems a little](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/8730)

Comment: I added the `Cargo.toml` file I'm using.

Comment: I've added the error message above.

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to have anything to do with creating a shared library (I get the same error in the playground), so I've changed the title to point to the part you're having trouble with right now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr** Use `Option` to represent nullable function pointers and `None` for null.

The error message is confusing, first, because `std::ptr::null_mut` isn't a pointer; it's a generic function that *returns* a pointer, and you haven't called it. So Rust is seeing you pass a function that has the wrong signature and calling convention, and complaining about that.

But once you fix that, you'll get this error instead:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:29:16
   |
29 |         hello: std::ptr::null_mut(),
   |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected fn pointer, found *-ptr
   |
   = note: expected type `extern "C" fn()`
              found type `*mut _`
```

Function pointers and object pointers are not compatible (this is also the case in C), so you can't cast between them. `null_mut` returns an object pointer, so you need to find another way to create a null function pointer.

Function pointers (values of type `fn(...) -> _`) have another interesting property: unlike raw pointers (`*const _` and `*mut _`), they can't be null. You don't need an `unsafe` block to call a function via pointer, and so creating a null function pointer is unsafe, like creating a null reference.

How do you make something nullable? Wrap it in `Option`:

```
#[repr(C)]
pub struct api {
    // ...
    load: Option<extern fn ()>,
    hello: Option<extern fn ()>, // assuming hello can also be null
}
```

And populate it with `Some(function)` or `None`:

```
let api = Box::new (api {
    // ...
    load: Some(hello_load),
    hello: None,
});
```

It's not usually a good idea to use `enum`s, including `Option`, in a `repr(C)` struct, because C doesn't have an `enum` equivalent and so you don't know what you're going to get on the other side. But in the case of `Option<T>` where `T` is something non-nullable, `None` is represented by the null value, so it should be okay.

The use of `Option` to represent a nullable function pointer for FFI is documented in the [Unsafe Code Guidelines](https://rust-lang.github.io/unsafe-code-guidelines/layout/function-pointers.html):

> null values are not supported by the Rust function pointer types -- just like references, the expectation is that you use `Option` to create nullable pointers. `Option<fn(Args...) -> Ret>` will have the exact same ABI as `fn(Args...) -> Ret`, but additionally allows null pointer values.