# What does transmute::<*mut c_void, Option<unsafe extern "C" fn() -> ()>> mean?

Tags: rust, ffi, unsafe

Here's some code I generated using [c2rust](https://c2rust.com) and then cleaned up a bit:

```
#![feature(libc)]
extern crate libc;

use libc::*;
use std::mem::transmute;

extern "C" {
    #[no_mangle]
    fn read(__fd: c_int, __buf: *mut c_void, __nbytes: c_ulong) -> c_long;
    #[no_mangle]
    fn mmap(
        __addr: *mut c_void,
        __len: c_ulong,
        __prot: c_int,
        __flags: c_int,
        __fd: c_int,
        __offset: c_long,
    ) -> *mut c_void;
}

pub fn main() {
    unsafe {
        let buf: *mut c_void = mmap(
            0 as *mut c_void,
            256i32 as c_ulong,
            0x1i32 | 0x2i32 | 0x4i32,
            0x2i32 | 0x20i32,
            -1i32,
            0i32 as c_long,
        );
        read(0i32, buf, 256i32 as c_ulong);
        transmute::<*mut c_void, Option<unsafe extern "C" fn() -> ()>>(buf).unwrap()();
    }
}
```

While I understand what it does, I'm not sure how to interpret the last expression. What does `Option<unsafe extern "C" fn() -> ()>` mean?

Comment: If you understand what it does, how can you not know what a line of code does? What exactly do you expect from an answer?

Comment: @Shepmaster basically I was trying to understand the strange syntax of casting to function pointers in Rust. I added an answer with my notes that details the pieces I don't understand yet.

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [How do I make a struct for FFI that contains a nullable function pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54572985/155423). If you disagree, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Answer (score -1):

We're trying to call an `unsafe extern "C" fn() -> ()`, which is basically a function with no arguments and no return type. My first attempt was to just use the `as` keyword, as defined in `transmute`'s documentation. I got the following error:

```
error[E0605]: non-primitive cast: `*mut libc::c_void` as `unsafe extern "C" fn()`
  --> wx.rs:32:9
   |
32 |         (buf as unsafe extern "C" fn() -> ())();
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: an `as` expression can only be used to convert between primitive types. Consider using the `From` trait
```

It looks like the function is a non-primitive type and this is why I need `transmute`. I tried the following:

```
transmute::<
    *mut c_void,
    unsafe extern "C" fn() -> ()
>(buf)();
```

And the code compiled and actually ran as expected.

What I still don't understand is why `Option` was used by c2rust, but the code works fine without it. It appears that `unsafe` and `extern "C"` can also be dropped and the code still works, at least for me.